# Weird behavior while parsing Json with a DoFn

Tags: java, json, apache-beam

I am trying to parse some Json that I have stored in google cloud storage. I am using apache beam to create a pipeline that reads the json stored and then writes it to a cloud sql database. I have encounter some weird behavior while writing my parse method.

Here is my Json:

```
        [{
            "projectid": "Reminder101",
            "reminderkey": "001",
            "localid": "01",
            "timestamp": "2018-01-24 12:00"
        },
        {
            "projectid": "Reminder101",
            "reminderkey": "002",
            "localid": "02",
            "timestamp": "2018-01-25 9:00"
        },
        {
            "projectid": "Reminder101",
            "reminderkey": "003",
            "localid": "03",
            "timestamp": "2018-02-01 18:00"
        },
        {
            "projectid": "Reminder101",
            "reminderkey": "004",
            "localid": "04",
            "timestamp": "2018-02-6 15:35"
        },
        {
            "projectid": "USReminder101",
            "reminderkey": "001",
            "localid": "01",
            "timestamp": "2018/01/30 21:00"
        }
    ]
```

Here is my json parse method(JsonHolder is just a pojo):

```
static class ParseJsonDoFn extends DoFn<String, List<JsonHolder>> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
    String incomingInfo = context.element();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(incomingInfo.toString());
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<JsonHolder>>(){}.getType();
    List<JsonHolder> jsonholders = gson.fromJson(incomingInfo, type);
    context.output(jsonholders);
  }
}
```

Now when I run my pipeline like this I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: 
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 
column 2 path $
```

The System.out.println(); shows:

```
"timestamp": "2018-02-01 18:00"
},
    "reminderkey": "004",
[{
    "localid": "01",
},
    "timestamp": "2018-01-24 12:00"
    "reminderkey": "002",
```

But, if I create a Json file that is a single line that is not formatted it parses fine. What I can deduce is that the Json file is being split after each end of line, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why or how to correct it.

Cheers.

Comment: Which input transform are you using to read the JSON file? I believe all of the transforms for reading files read the file line by line. Therefore, formatted, multiline JSON objects would be broken apart. I don't think there is a way around this.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextIO.read() reads text files, returning each line as a separate element of the PCollection. This is done so that it can work on files of unlimited size without loading the file contents in memory.

If your input format is not line-delimited, you probably want the more flexible FileIO: match() to find the files that match your filepatterns of interest, read() to automatically decompress them and get a convenient handle on the file contents as a ReadableFile. Then parse the file in whichever way you want using a DoFn.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the information. I'll give what you suggested a go and see if I can make it work!